# Dotnet does not see files on docker volume

Tags: .net, docker

I'm having problems with running `dotnet restore` and other commands inside Docker environment.
Setup is:

- docker-compose
- docker
- dotnet

My dockerfile looks like that

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.app
    volumes:
      - "./app:/app"
```

and what I am trying to achieve with dockerfile is to build once and then watch for changes, and rebuild - so I do not want to copy files, want to mount them for watching

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0

WORKDIR /app

RUN dotnet restore 
RUN dotnet publish 

CMD ["dotnet", "watch", "build"]
```

and the error is

```
 > [3/4] RUN dotnet restore:
#5 0.423 MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.
```

I've tried to define multiple types of path for the project but without any good result

Answer (score 0):

Because volume is mapped only when the Dockerfile has been built successfully.

You have to copy the `app` folder to build the image first.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN dotnet restore 
RUN dotnet publish 

CMD ["dotnet", "watch", "build"]
```

Could you please try it again?

Comment: Yes, that basically makes it work but how it will allow me to do a hot reload on changes detected? Will it detect the changes then?

Comment: Yes it should be. Just keep the volume mapping in docker conpose file.

Comment: Okay, I'll give it a chance and take a look on. Thank you for the quick response.